# CSS3 column flow around other elements?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery-mobile, mobile, sass

I am currently developing a page for mobile.

It requires a form that divides into two columns in landscape mode. Above the form I would like to place two divs where both have different heights.

I would like to adjust each column's y-position according to those divs.

Can I use CSS3-columns in this scenario?

The technologies I can use are HTML, SASS, JQuery Mobile and Javascript.

[image: Here is an image to make it clearer]

Comment: You could make use of **Bootstrap** to achieve this or **CSS3 Flexbox**

Comment: Unfortunately I can't really use a whole new styling framework just for this issue..

Comment: Then flexbox is your solution, its not a framework - Its just a layout mode introduced as part of CSS3 itself. [Read here](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_flexbox.asp)

Comment: Oh ok, I used bootstrap before so I thought flexbox was along those lines. Awesome, thank you.

Comment: No worries .. Cheers!